# What is the acceleration experienced by a person walking into a tree or pole?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, collision, elasticity

Please go to this [website](http://showvideos123.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com) and view videos of people walking into things. I would like to know what is the deceleration their head experiences from this.

I have done my research on this already. A person walks on average between $1 ~ mph - 3.1 ~ mph$ ($0.80 ~ m/s - 1.40 ~ m/s$) You can use two formulas to calculate the deceleration experienced (preferably in $gs$ concussions occur around $90 ~ gs$ and sub concussions can occur over $10 ~ gs$) The formulas that can be used is

$$a = \frac{\Delta v}{t} \tag{1} \label{1} $$

or

$$ a = \frac{\Delta v^{2}}{2 \Delta D} \tag{2} \label{2} $$

The problem I have is what I should use for $t$ and $\Delta D$. Also, how do I take into account the elasticity of objects which change the time or distance required to go from initial velocity to $0$ and have a huge impact on acceleration experienced? For instance, if a person is wearing a hat and hits a tree or a person without a hat hits his head on bare concrete.

Comment: What is it? It's hard to compute is what. Unless you start with "Assume a spherical head..." Assume everything's made of simple, homogenous materials with well-known mechanical properties, and in simple, geometric shapes. Otherwise, you're better off obtaining the data empirically. Maybe set up an experiment using [these guys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_test_dummy).

Comment: Do you know if any researchers that I have done this? Maybe send me a research paper link.

Comment: I used Algodoo software to test it out. You can see the video on the website. It was about 10gs to 11gs. This is enough to cause a subconcussion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if someone walks into a pole, their velocity goes from $0.80 m/s$ to $0 m/s$ in a very small time interval, so acceleration would be infinite, since time approaches zero. With the work-energy method, however, you can look at it as a collision between head and pole, as result of which they both exert impulsive forces on each other. $$I=\Delta p$$ (for collisions)
$$I=mv$$ (final velocity of the person is zero)
$$acceleration=\frac{I}m$$
$$I=v$$
(magnitude wise)